# Removing specific element from a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have a list of indices and values.

```
indx_list <- list(1,2,c(3,4),5,c(6,7,8))
val_list <- list(0.1,0.6,c(0.8,0.9),0.3,c(0.4,0.8,0.5))
```

I then want to update both lists by removing indices `c(4,7)` and the corresponding values `c(0.9,0.5)`. This is pretty easily done using `lapply` and `setdiff`. For example:

```
indx_list_new <- lapply(indx_list,function(x) setdiff(x,c(4,7)))
val_list_new <- lapply(val_list,function(x) setdiff(x,c(0.9,0.5)))
```

However, I don't know beforehand what indices and corresponding values I will be removing.

```
set.seed(1234)
indx_flag <- sample(seq(8),2)
```

You can also see that some values are repeated (i.e. 0.8) so using `setdiff` might actually remove values at the wrong position.

### Questions

1) I can still use `lapply` and `setdiff` to update `indx_list`, but how can I update the values in `val_list`?

2) Is `lapply` the most efficient solution here? I will have lists with thousands of elements, and each element can be a vector of hundreds of indices/values.

### Edit

Each element in the list (highest level) actually has a particular meaning, so I'd like to keep the list structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, arrange your data into a 'tidy' representation

```
df = data.frame(
    indx = unlist(indx_list),
    val = unlist(val_list),
    grp = factor(rep(seq_along(indx_list), lengths(indx_list)))
)
```

where the operation is more-or-less transparent

```
base::subset(df, !indx %in% c(4, 7))
  indx val grp
1    1 0.1   1
2    2 0.6   2
3    3 0.8   3
5    5 0.3   4
6    6 0.4   5
8    8 0.5   5
```

Using `subset()` is similar to `df[!df$indx %in% c(4, 7), , drop = FALSE]`. (I used `factor()` to allow for empty groups, i.e., levels with no corresponding values).

Comment: Thanks. I should add that I would prefer to keep the list structure since the elements at the highest level actually have a particular meaning.

Comment: The list structure is present in the `grp` column, so there's no loss of information. Rectangular data is easier to reason about compared to lists-of-lists, etc.

Comment: Yes, you could recover the list that way, but really I'm suggesting that you do not use lists at all. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt using `relist` and `Map` to remove the same points:

```
Map(`[`, val_list, relist(!unlist(indx_list) %in% c(4,7), indx_list))
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.6
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 0.8
# 
#[[4]]
#[1] 0.3
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 0.4 0.5
```